# Create another TAG widget for posts

Tags: tags, post-editor

Currently, Posts have "tags" and in the post edit page you can add and remove tags using the widget.

I would like to add another such tag-system (say, keywords) and I would like for it to use the tag interface to add and remove tags.

Suggestion on how I should go about this ?

Comment: In addition to or in replace of the native support for tags?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use register_taxonomy with hierarchical set to false:

```
function add_custom_taxonomies() {
// Add new "Locations" taxonomy to Posts
register_taxonomy('keyword', 'post', array (
        'hierarchical' = false
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomies', 0 );
```

For more information: 
- [Wordpress API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)
- [Tutorial @ Smashing magazine](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/04/create-custom-taxonomies-wordpress/)